# scope of Meteor.userId() Anywhere but publish function

Tags: meteor

With many trial and error being one client logged in, Meteor.userId() seams to work anyWhere. Due to the app nature, it is not so easy to simulate with multi logins for now.

Is it expected that Meteor keeps track with which user calling which method, specially when said method calls public_method_A which calls private_method_B where methods A,B belong to a module in the global scope?

I tried it with one user logged in and found that Meteor.userId() gave correct info. [doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_userid) says Anywhere but publish function.
Q. Do I ever need to pass userId in any function arguments or just user Meteor.userId() whenever I need it and trust that Meteor.userId() will always get the id of the user who called the very first client side method?
Thanks

**edit**
If Meteor.userId() is used every where a userId is needed in the server code. Isn't this "function call" expensive comparing to passing an argument?
If so, it is OK to create a global scope `const userId=Meteor.userId()` variable in the server global scope? i.e. (if every client gets a new server instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is it expected that Meteor keeps track with which user is calling which method?**

Yes, this is true in a client-initiated call. `Meteor.userId()` will be correct in all cases, even when the calls are chained.

Note, however, that `this.userId` will always return the correct value inside of the first method call, but will not persist to subsequent calls unless their context is bound to the caller's context.

**Do I ever need to pass userId in any function arguments?**

As pointed out in [the guide](http://guide.meteor.com/security.html#user-id-client), you should not pass the user's id to a method call. In the best case it's redundant, and in the worst case it's a major security hole.

If a method call is initiated by the client (this is common), you can rely on `Meteor.userId()` being correct. If any function call (method or otherwise) is initiated from the server (this is not common), then `Meteor.userId()` will not be available.

Comment: is not passing userId as an argument  less expensive than function call Meter.userId(), specially when it is being used many times in different places in the server side?

Comment: Not really. `Meteor.userId()` just reads from the current connection settings - it doesn't have to hit the database, so it's a trivial operation.